Should I wrap my SVG <g> group in an <a> tag or wrap each elements within this group in a <a> tag in an interactive map?
I am working on an interactive SVG map of France, where each region is represented by a  group that contains multiple  elements. The map needs to be accessible, and I want to ensure I follow best practices for web accessibility.
Here is a simplified version of my SVG:
<svg viewBox="0 0 800 759" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" width="100%" height="100%" aria-labelledby="description">
    <desc id="description">Carte de France avec ses régions</desc>
    <g aria-describedby="tooltip-11">
        <a href="/">
            <path d="M 437.43 178.76 432.8 186.13 436.69 187.81 436.25 194.54 439.8 195.32 436.54 201.09 437.29 203.08 432.78 207.96 433.95 215.41 431.33 216.85 425.49 217.44 419.32 216.88 414.47 218.03 412.81 222.13 414.44 224.95 412.41 229.38 408.67 233.45 403.34 235.78 399.06 234.83 396.28 236.53 393.12 235.48 386.63 236.22 383.36 235.47 386.73 230.89 381.28 222.38 368.67 221.47 361.25 223.54 356.95 221.57 358.3 217.48 357.8 214.23 354.31 211.14 351.12 210.5 347.98 207.05 347.66 202.08 343.7 199.45 338.51 192.75 337.4 190.05 339.97 186.45 337.34 183 337.9 177.5 335.59 172.52 333.68 171.02 330.97 162.6 338.93 159.77 341.85 156.21 343.1 149.7 344.67 148.08 347.23 152.71 349.75 151.91 354.49 153.49 360.12 152.78 363.77 150.58 365.77 151.98 371.43 152.62 373.18 154.78 376.29 152.17 386.14 157.66 393.03 158.94 399.19 162.24 402.09 159.33 405.26 161.51 414.64 160.25 415.54 158.01 419.17 158.53 421.94 163.41 420.83 165.72 427.95 171.11 429.31 174.29 437.43 178.76 Z"
                  data-name="Île-de-France"/>
            <path d="M 377.02 181.46 371.4 178.51 376.45 174.83 381.46 178.93 377.02 181.46 Z" data-name="Paris" id="75"/>
            <path d="M 389.53 191.46 390.63 182.32 389.15 175.77 390.78 171.2 388.72 166.21 390.67 160.68 393.03 158.94 399.19 162.24 414.64 160.25 415.78 157.73 420.64 159.14 420.83 165.72 427.95 171.11 429.31 174.29 437.43 178.76 432.8 186.13 436.69 187.81 436.25 194.54 441.25 197.12 432.78 207.96 433.95 215.41 425.49 217.44 414.47 218.03 414.44 224.95 408.67 233.45 403.34 235.78 399.06 234.83 386.63 236.22 386.73 230.89 380.44 220.87 384.24 215.36 386.47 206.28 385.66 203.27 389.53 191.46 Z" data-name="Seine-et-Marne" id="77"/>
            <path d="M 370.2 174.12 367.58 181.37 371.47 184.65 365.83 187.27 360.95 193.97 360.26 201.86 355.9 202.52 355.15 209.73 351.12 210.5 347.98 207.05 347.66 202.08 343.7 199.45 337.4 190.05 339.97 186.45 337.34 183 337.9 177.5 333.68 171.02 330.97 162.6 339.49 160.27 345.4 162.99 350.94 160.57 356.59 164.97 364.25 165.65 370.52 170.85 370.2 174.12 Z" data-name="Yvelines" id="78"/>
            <path d="M 371.47 184.65 376.39 186.87 389.53 191.46 385.66 203.27 386.47 206.28 384.24 215.36 380.44 220.87 368.67 221.47 358.76 223.33 358.3 217.48 355.15 209.73 355.9 202.52 360.26 201.86 360.95 193.97 365.83 187.27 371.47 184.65 Z" data-name="Essonne" id="91"/>
            <path d="M 374.97 170.81 376.45 174.83 371.4 178.51 377.02 181.46 376.39 186.87 371.47 184.65 367.58 181.37 370.2 174.12 374.97 170.81 Z" data-name="Hauts-de-Seine" id="92"/>
            <path d="M 388.72 166.21 390.78 171.2 389.15 175.77 390.63 182.32 386.13 178.33 381.46 178.93 376.45 174.83 374.97 170.81 378.89 169.01 383.64 170.5 388.72 166.21 Z" data-name="Seine-Saint-Denis" id="93"/>
            <path d="M 377.02 181.46 381.46 178.93 386.13 178.33 390.63 182.32 389.53 191.46 376.39 186.87 377.02 181.46 Z" data-name="Val-de-Marne" id="94"/>
            <path d="M 390.67 160.68 388.72 166.21 383.64 170.5 378.89 169.01 374.97 170.81 370.2 174.12 370.52 170.85 364.25 165.65 356.59 164.97 350.94 160.57 345.4 162.99 339.49 160.27 344.67 148.08 347.23 152.71 354.49 153.49 363.77 150.58 371.43 152.62 376.29 152.17 390.67 160.68 Z" data-name="Val-d'Oise" id="95"/>
        </a>
    </g>
</svg>
<span id="tooltip-11" role="tooltip" class="tooltip placement">Île-de-France</span>

I am unsure whether I should:

Wrap the entire <g> group in a single <a> tag.
Wrap each <path> element within the <g> group in a single <a> tag (that's what I've done in the provided example).

Additionally, I want to ensure that the SVG element has the correct role. Should it be role="img" or something else, given the interactivity?

 can group elements just like  so why use a  at all. You'd only wrap each path if you wanted to provide different links for each path.

@RobertLongson I was planning to use  but yeah you're probably right, I'll get rid of the 

 should always be a last resort. It's almost always a) overkill b) bad for performance c) does not save you what you think it's saving you.

What is the purpose of the department paths within the IDF if they are not visible and cannot be interacted with? Are you really looking for a link? Will it navigate to another page?

Is there any reason you’re using <desc> instead of <title>?

Stepping through several links with the same destination would be quite cumbersome for keyboard users.
Having one link only is the best solution and recommended by the WCAG Techniques.
That is if no other interaction with single departments within the Île-de-France is possible.
Any link needs an accessible name, though.
<a href="/" aria-label="Île-de-France">

Consider relying on SVG’s default role, as quite some thought went into it. That means simply don’t add the role attribute.
If you’re uncertain, you might use role="figure":

figure (role)
A perceivable section of content that typically contains a graphical document, images, code snippets, or example text. The parts of a figure MAY be user-navigable.


Further, you should not use the <desc> element for a short description, and at the same time provide the accessible name. Otherwise, it might be read twice to screen reader users.
Use <title> instead, the default means to provide an accessible name.
